# BackEnd side is on Java or in Java language?

Tags: word-difference

FrontEnd in Angular
BackEnd side of the project is on Java?

ON, IN or WITH
How to say properly?

Comment: The front end in Angular is in JavaScript (or, if you prefer, ECMAScript ), not Java. The back end for Angular projects can be written in Java or any other appropriate server-side language. It's hard to tell what you're talking about when you include both the way you've done.

Comment: I understood what OP meant: front end in Angular; back end in Java. That's perfectly normal to say.

Comment: It's pretty clear that the querent is interested in the usage ***on Java*** vs ***in Java***, and the answer addresses that.

Comment: "Backend side" is redundant. Better to say: "The front end is in Angular, the back end is in Java."

Comment: If we don't encourage clear punctuation, who's being served?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A software project is usually described as being written **in** a language

> The server code is in Java
>
> The back end is written in Java

(Note: "back end" and "front end" are usually two words, not camel-cased. as an adjective, you might see them hyphenated "back-end")

Comment: *back end* and *front end* are often two words when used as nouns in their own right, but can occasionally be found as a single word, possibly hyphenated, especially when used as an adjective: "The backend processing is being done on a Bigiron5000." "We need the back-end code to be rewritten in REBOL."

Comment: I was using it as a participial phrase; i.e. an adjective, describing text as "camel-cased" is reasonable and I've definitely used it that way before. "not a verb in any case"? I find that to be a very strong assertion. Probably not commonly used in any case. "eques[trian]" what's that for?